# Wordpress API only returning HTML

Tags: custom-post-types, api, json

I am making the following POST request to my wordpress site's api to create a new post in a Custom Post Type called "service."

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/service/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Basic ",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\n\t\"title\": \"The Service\",\n\t\"status\":\"publish\",\n\t\"fields\": {\n\t\t\"overview\": \"A bunch of content\",\n        \"extra\": \"Notes here\"\n\t}\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The request is working fine and creating the new service, however I am only getting a HTML response instead of JSON like I am requesting using the "accept" header. My wordpress version is 4.8.2.

How do I force my wordpress site to return JSON instead of HTML?

Comment: Have you tried setting the ajax dataType option to json?

Comment: yes, no luck with that either. If i use the same request in postman, I have the same problem as well

Comment: No clue. I'm guessing when you go to the json url (using the browser) you actually see json, right?

Comment: Any reason the data object is escaped? Should be able to pass a JavaScript object, not a string.